# How to keep the authentication status for twitter to avoid login each time I open the App

Tags: android, twitter

I created android app has "login with twitter account" feature and this app reads the followers list on twitter.
I do not have any problem in the login but my problem is how to keep the app always logged in on twitter without asking the user again to sign in with twitter.

In the first time, the user will be asked to give my app this permission and the user will authorize my app on that.
If the user close the app and open it again without relogin to twitter then he tried to get the followers list using the following code:

```
ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(twitterUserId, cursor);
```

I will got error:

```
04-06 12:04:41.881: E/AndroidRuntime(28630):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-06 12:04:41.881: E/AndroidRuntime(28630): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication     credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details
04-06 12:04:41.881: E/AndroidRuntime(28630):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:201)
```

When I tried to do relogin by code using the below method reLoginOnTwitter after saving the TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN, TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_SECRET and TWITTER_VERIFIER from the first success login, I got error:

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
```

Can anyone help me since I tried a lot to search on it but I did not find any useful solution for this problem.

My working login code and the relogin method code are below:

```
public static Twitter twitter;
public void twitterLogin(Activity activity) {
    String authUrl = null;
    twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

    try {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        String callbackurlWithParams = CALLBACKURL;
        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackurlWithParams);
        authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();

        saveTwitterRequestData(requestToken.getToken(), requestToken.getTokenSecret(), activity);
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));
        it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        activity.startActivity(it);

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected exception while login with twitter :" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

After that I read the verifier in the onResume method and complete twitter login.

```
public boolean reLoginOnTwitter(Activity activity) {
        try {

            if (twitter == null) {
        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
                    }

            SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences(AppConstant.APP_PREF, 0);
            final String verifier = prefs.getString(TWITTER_VERIFIER, null);
                            String reqToken = prefs.getString(TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN, null);
                    String reqTokenSecret = prefs.getString(TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_SECRET, null);
                    RequestToken  requestToken = new RequestToken(reqToken, reqTokenSecret);

            if (requestToken != null) {


                new AsyncTask<Void,Object, IDs>() {
                    String error = null;
                    @Override
                    protected IDs doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        try {
                            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                        } catch (TwitterException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    return null;    
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(IDs Ids) {
                    }
                }.execute();

              return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "request failed due to unexpected exception :" + e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    return false;
}
```